# more efficient writing of multiple properties regarding media query in tailwind css

Tags: media-queries, tailwind-css

so up until the time of writing ive been doing media query this way
`className="text-white text-[1.2rem]     lg:text-blue lg:text-[2.5rem]"`

are there any methods to write multiple media query properties in "one place" without manually repeating the " lg: " part?

im hoping for something like/close to this
`className="lg:{text-blue text-[1.2rem]}"`

where properties for the same media query are grouped neatly

Answer (score 0):

tailwindcss by default doesn't support variant groups yet, but you can customize variants. [read more](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants)

also you can use other libraries like [Windi css](https://windicss.org/) or [Unocss](https://uno.antfu.me/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for now, `tailwindcss` doesn't support variant groups .

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design